# What would make a planet have a different sky colour?

Tags: science-based

If I have an earth type planet with a slightly higher cloud cover (62%) and a brighter star  (1.22), would the sky change colour?

Comment: -1 because you haven't searched this Stack. We have a LOT of questions about sky color here. Rayleigh Scattering always scatters in the blue spectrum (regardless of atmospheric density), but star color can shift it. We have a Q that has a chart of what colors you can expect with star color shifts. You can put dust or other materials in the air to change the color... all of which (and more) you would have learned had you done some research. Also, your title and the question in the body of your post should match. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you watch the Youtube video: [SKY & PLANT COLOR ft. Worldbuilding Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9MNC45Jr6Q&ab_channel=Artifexian). The video explains how cloud cover and star size or brightness could affect sky color.

Answer (score 7):

Expect your sky to have a more violet-blue hue than Earth’s.

The colour of a planet’s sky mostly depends on its atmospheric density and composition, and its star’s stellar classification. In the case of your planet, I’ll assume atmospheric composition is near identical to Earth’s, except for your outlined factors.

A higher cloud coverage suggests more water on the planet’s surface, and more water vapor in the air, but even a planet with twice as much water vapor as Earth wouldn’t see much change to its atmosphere’s appearance, except for maybe a slightly more pronounced blue hue. This would be very hard to notice, and would probably be a detail left out.

Rayleigh scattering, the main principle behind atmospheric colour, means that your atmosphere will let attain the brighter wavelengths of your stars’ spectrum. For an Earth-like atmosphere, this means a dim, M class star would produce a butterscotch-orange colour, a sol-like G class star would produce a familiar white-blue, and a blazing hot A class star would produce a harsh violet. A star with 1.22 times solar masses or luminosity would veer on the edge between G class and F class, and likely produce a noticeably more violet atmosphere than Earth’s.

If you put these two together, you get an atmosphere with hints of purple and just a little bit of deeper blues. Otherwise, your clouds would look the same.

Comment: A class star wouldn't produce violet sky (at least if we only take into account Rayleigh scattering). The sky of an Earth-like planet illuminated by a 10000K star (assuming blackbody spectrum), assuming the atmospheric composition doesn't change, will be just more saturated blue, not violet. See also [my answer at Astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43814/735) regarding the colors of sky with different illuminants and pressures.

Answer (score 3):

**Going out of the range of normal sequence stars can make for some unexpected effects. For example...**

A small white dwarf with a temperature of 60000K will have peak emission at 5nm (about 2.5 keV) - which is soft X-ray - an ionizing by [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) radiation.

[image]

A thick atmosphere on your planet will make the surface safe from the ionisation damage, even more so with a good cloud coverage. The recombination of ionized species with the electrons in upper atmosphere will give you a kaleidoscope of colors. Very much like the Northern Lights, except it will happen on all latitudes and will be visible even at daytime.

That generalized aurora can actually be the main source of daylight, since only 1.22 brightness of a star with a 60000k surface temperature can be achieved with a very small star radius (the [radiant emittance is $7.349e11 W/m^2$](https://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody_calculator/blackbody.php))

If you want to add a reasonable magnetic field of the planet you'll get an [interesting dynamic of the colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish_Prime).

Answer (score 1):

Different color star = different light coming in. Think a blue star, a red dwarf, or similar.

Different atmospheric composition = different refraction of light coming in. Compare: water drops refract light different to water vapor. And even an Earthly example: average cloud is white, because the water particles refract the light different to the oxygen-nitrogen fix of atmosphere. But, too much (closer to raining) and it turns a dark, broody gray, before approaching black.

Also consider storms and sunsets. These offer different stimuli and can therefore have different colors.

An example: Mars sky is orangey-red. towards sunset, the sky turns blue (inverse of Earth, because of the same principle of light refracting due to angle of incoming light breaking differently).

Another example: the 'green glow' just as sun is setting on Earth. Atmospheric conditions must be 'just right' for this effect.

A third example: airborne algae/gases absorbing certain light waves or refracting light differently. (see Purple Earth Hypothesis for further details)

So. It's easy to say that the sky can be a host of different colors for a host of different reasons. One would need to know the color of host star, atmospheric composition and conditions, and weather conditions to say with any accuracy how this affects the general color of the sky.